# Remove first occurrence of comma in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking for a way to remove the first occurrence of a comma in a string, for example

```
"some text1, some tex2, some text3"
```

should return instead:

```
"some text1 some text2, some tex3"
```

So, the function should only look if there's more than one comma, and if there is, it should remove the first occurrence. This could be probably solved with the regex but I don't know how to write it, any ideas ?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This will do it:

```
if (str.match(/,.*,/)) { // Check if there are 2 commas
    str = str.replace(',', ''); // Remove the first one
}
```

When you use the `replace` method with a string rather than an RE, it just replaces the first match.

Comment: "So, the function should only look if there's more than one comma, and if there is, it should remove the first occurrence. ". I don't want to remove comma if there's only one in string.

Answer (score 19):

[`String.prototype.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) replaces only the first occurence of the match:

```
"some text1, some tex2, some text3".replace(',', '')
// => "some text1 some tex2, some text3"
```

Global replacement occurs only when you specify the regular expression with `g` flag.

---

```
var str = ",.,.";
if (str.match(/,/g).length > 1) // if there's more than one comma
    str = str.replace(',', '');
```

Comment: If nothing is exist on **str** then it'll throw **length undefined property error**. So use optional chain to avoid that. Example 
```if(str.match(/,/g)?.length > 1)```

Answer (score 2):

A simple one liner will do it:

```js
text = text.replace(/^(?=(?:[^,]*,){2})([^,]*),/, '$1');
```

Here is how it works:

```py
regex = re.compile(r"""
    ^                # Anchor to start of line|string.
    (?=              # Look ahead to make sure
      (?:[^,]*,){2}  # There are at least 2 commas.
    )                # End lookahead assertion.
    ([^,]*)          # $1: Zero or more non-commas.
    ,                # First comma is to be stripped.
    """, re.VERBOSE)
```

Comment: It's not really "simple" when you use a regex with lookahead and whatnot, but I get your point. I would use a simpler regex. `replace(/^([^,]*),/, '$1')` (get all chars form start until first comma and group, add first comma, replace all with group). BUT as said above by someone else, `replace` stops at first occurence, so it's better suited for the job when not using regex.

Answer (score 2):

you could also use a lookahead like so `^(.*?),(?=.*,)` and replace w/ `$1`
[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/rW6nV1)

Answer (score 1):

a way with split:

```
var txt = 'some text1, some text2, some text3';

var arr = txt.split(',', 3);

if (arr.length == 3)
    txt = arr[0] + arr[1] + ',' + arr[2];
```

or shorter:

```
if ((arr = txt.split(',', 3)).length == 3)
    txt = arr[0] + arr[1] + ',' + arr[2];
```

If there are less than 3 elements in the array (less than 2 commas) the string stay unchanged. The split method use the limit parameter (set to 3), as soon as the limit of 3 elements is reached, the split method stops.

or with replace:

```
txt = txt.replace(/,(?=[^,]*,)/, '');
```