# Remove ONLY a Single instance of a character from a String Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a string `"QAWABAWONL"`, from which I want to remove ONLY a single occurrence of the character 'A'. It does not matter whether the first occurrence or the second occurrence gets removed, either is fine. I've found that using `indexOf` or `includes` removes all occurrences.

Comment: Please include any code that you have already tried.

Comment: "using indexOf or includes removes all occurences" is not necessarily true... `indexOf` only returns the index or `-1`, it doesn't remove anything. `includes` method returns true or false, it also doesn't remove anything

Answer (score 2):

I'ts simple, there are many ways of doing this. I would use a regex:

```
myStr.replace(/A/i, "");
```

The `i` flag is for ignoring case. If you wanted to replace more than one occurrence you need the `g` flag but it's not your case.

Answer (score 1):

Use [String.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and pass a substring for the first argument.

From the above link (emphasis mine):

> substr (pattern)
>
> A String that is to be replaced by newSubStr. It is treated as a verbatim string and is not interpreted as a regular expression. **Only the first occurrence will be replaced.**

Usage:

```js
let originalString = "QAWABAWONL";
let result = originalString.replace("A","");

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression in jscript, it's so easy:
example: alert("some text1, some tex2, some text3".replace('text1', ''));
[Remove first occurrence of comma in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23970079/remove-first-occurrence-of-comma-in-a-string)

I hope it is useful !